# Execute a statement after calls.enqueue is executed, retrofit

Tags: json, retrofit2

I've created a class for `calls.enqueue` and it should return the `json` which is received in `onResponse`

Class:

```
class EnqueueCalls
{ 
    private static JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject enqueue(Call<ResponseBody> calls, final Boolean jsonExist, final Context context)
    {
        calls.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response)
            {
                        object = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception :: " + t.toString());
            }
        });

        Log.e(TAG, "I'm not in enqueue" + object); //when this method is called, control is coming here first
        return object;
    }
```

When I'm calling this method, it is returning the empty `object` then `calls.enqueue` is executed and `json` value is assigned to `object`.

How do I return the `object` value which is assigned in `onResponse`?

Basically, I want the `return` statement to execute after `calls.enqueue` is executed.

I've tried:

```
void enqueues(Call<ResponseBody> calls, final Boolean jsonExist, final Context context)
{
    calls.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()
    { /*get json here*/ }
}

JSONObject getObject() {
    return object;
}
```

And called it

```
enqueueCalls.enqueues(calls, true, this);
object = enqueueCalls.getObject();
```

Still I get the empty object.

Comment: enqueue is asynchronous, that is why you have the callback, and the callback code is only executed after the network request finishes.

Comment: yeah right @Bhargav what should I do in order to return the json after `onResponse`

Comment: you don't understand something fundamental about this, the code that you have written in the callback happens after your function completes execution, (and maybe even later, don't know when it will be run thats the point), so there is no such thing as `returning`, whenever network request finishes you need to execute the code which requires the object sent by the server, so whatever code depends on the object's data you need to put it inside the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Instead of returning the json Handling the json in same class is a
>   good option.

So what so ever need to be done with the response should be handled only in `onResponse`.

I'm calling a method `handleResponse(callBackResponse)` which will take care of the headers, json etc. by using the received response.

**Reason:**

Can't control the response time and execution of callback methods. We can't say it to execute `calls.enqueue` first, then execute the return statement.

Looking forward for some better solution, if exists.

**EDIT**

At the time of this Question, was completely unaware about these Synchronous and asynchronous methods, callbacks. As mentioned by @bhargav there is no such thing called **returning** in these callbacks.

*Solution*
Call other methods based on the response and pass this response.

```
@override
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
     if (response.code() == 200) {

            // success
            try {
                String responseString;
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    responseString = response.body().string();
                    onApiSuccess(responseString);
                } else {
                    onApiFailure("Server side error: Empty response");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                onApiFailure("Server side error: " + e);
            }
     }
}
```